# District/province wise air quality data for South Asia (2010 onward)

Tags: remote-sensing, air-pollution, air-quality

I would like to create a district/province-level air quality data for all the countries in South Asia from 2010 onward using satellite data.

As someone with absolutely zero background in remote-sensing, could anyone please suggest (relevant papers, websites, anything really) how do I go on about this?

Thank you!

Comment: What temporal resolution do you need?  Average overall, per month, per day?

Comment: i'm looking for daily average.

Comment: Daily average might be difficult, as it's hard to measure air quality from space when it's cloudy.

Comment: Absolutely. That makes sense. What do you think would be a reasonable option then - weekly/fortnightly?

Comment: The longer the averaging time and averaging area, the less gaps you will get. Monthly gridded data can be downloaded directly.  I don't have time for a full answer, but have a look at [Sentinel-5 data](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-5/data-products) which could be a good start.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll take a look.